# WCF Asynch pattern - Really required?

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

I have created one WCF service which performs a lengthy operation asynchronously using Asynch pattern.  I have referred to below link to implement  `BeginAddNumbers` and `EndAddNumbers` methods in the ServiceContract.
http://aspalliance.com/1335_Asynchronous_Pattern_in_Windows_Communication_Foundation.5
Everything  is working fine.  But I dont understand why we require this approach?

```
Even though its asynchronous operation on server, client will still blocked and we 
have to invoke this operation asynchornously on client as well.  
So instead of implementing operation asynchronously on server it's always 
better to invoke operation asynchronously on client side to have responsive UI.
```

Can anyone help me to understand concept of implementing asynchronous operation on server side?  Any practical example where I need to play around `AsyncPattern=true` in conjunction with `OperationContract` ?

Adding client code.  Client is implemented using WPF application

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MathOperationClient c = new MathOperationClient();
        Task t = new Task(new Action(() =>
        {                
            ///Even if AddNumbers is is implemented as asynchronous operation
            ///second call to AddNumbers get chance only after completing below
            ///call.  
            ///Note: AddNumbers method takes 10 sec to execute
            int nResult = c.AddNumbers(2, 3);                
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{
                label1.Content = nResult.ToString();
            })
           , null);
        }));


        t.Start();


        Task t1 = new Task(new Action(() =>
        {
            ///Below method is invoked only after executing first call ( above call with parameters 2 and 3 ) 
            ///in other words below call is blocked for 10 seconds.
            ///So what is advantage of implementing asynchronous AddNumbers method on server side?
            int result = c.AddNumbers(5,5);

            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                label2.Content = result.ToString();
            })
           , null);
        }));

        t1.Start();
    }
```

Thanks, Hemant

Comment: http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/20/async-operations-in-wcf-iasyncresult-model-client-side/ - the link is dead to me, does it work for you ? it provides the best example and explanation i have encountered for implementing IAsyncResult Pattern

Comment: @ilansch Thanks, but the link is not accessible for me either.

Comment: http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/asynchronous-operations-in-wcf.html Try this sample, the point is that when calling to Service, you should send the operation to be in a new thread. the BeginOperation should not do most of work, you should queue the real heavy operation in new thread.

Comment: How are you creating the client? Is it via the Visual Studio add service reference?

Comment: @Aron I have added client code and some comment to make my question clear.

Comment: @user2243747 I meant the client proxy.

Comment: @Aron yes, you are right.  I have added proxy using visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

[this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73506/Summarizing-Client-Side-Asynchronous-Invocations-i) has some information.

in general:

> In case of WCF, the realproxy is of type System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy. This proxy implementation calls service method synchronously even if we call it using BeginInvoke. 
>   WCF only issues asynchronous calls if the method that is called on a proxy begins with BeginXXX() and is decorated with [OperationContract(AsyncPattern=true)] attribute.

Comment: @lgarioshka Thaks.  But my question is what advantage do I get using this approach?  Even if WCF issues asynchronous call client UI still blocks unless method returns.  Am I right?

Comment: @user2243747 when WCF service is using the pattern, you may call it from the client asynchronously so that the UI would not freeze.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea to implement this server side; and clearly indicate this by naming the operation accordingly. After all, if a call is asynchronous in nature, why give the client the choice?

Another reason is scalability: doing it server-side decouples the request from the WCF dispatcher thread. This means that WCF threads will not be blocked.

See [here](http://piers7.blogspot.it/2009/09/implementing-asynchronous-operations-in.html) for an example.

You could even decide to make it a one way call; and have the client poll at regular intervals; which is, in fact, my favorite approach.